# Regex to extract top level domain from email address

Tags: python, regex, tld

From email address like

```
xxx@site.co.uk
xxx@site.uk
xxx@site.me.uk
```

I want to write a regex which should return 'uk' is all the cases.

I have tried

```
'+@([^.]+)\..+'
```

which gives only the domain name. I have tried using

```
'[^/.]+$'
```

but it is giving error.

Comment: What error are you getting for the last one? And could you show the actual code you're using?

Comment: How about simply `.+@.+(\.[\w+])`?

Comment: Is a regex necessary? How about `email_address.rsplit(".", 1)[1]`?

Comment: Are these separate strings? Then you can just do `\w+$`

Comment: This is part of big code, which supports regex only.
But somehow `\w+$` is working, thnks @UlugbekUmirov

Comment: @amitbisai Your second regex is almost correct. You just used wrong escaping symbol. It should be `\`` - `[^\.]+$`.

Answer (score 3):

The regex to extract what you are asking for is:

```
\.([^.\n\s]*)$  with /gm modifiers
```

explanation:

```
    \. matches the character . literally
1st Capturing group ([^.\n\s]*)
    [^.\n\s]* match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        . the literal character .
        \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
$ assert position at end of a line
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
g modifier: global. All matches
```

for your input example, it will be:

```
import re
m = re.compile(r'\.([^.\n\s]*)$', re.M)                                             
f = re.findall(m, data)                                                             
print f
```

output:

```
['uk', 'uk', 'uk']
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As `myemail@com` is a valid address, you can use:

```
@.*([^.]+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex. This would always give you 'uk' in your examples:

```
>>> url = 'foo@site.co.uk'
>>> url.split('.')[-1]
'uk'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `.*\.(\w+)` won't help?

Can add more validations for "@" to the regular expression if needed.